# i want to show a panel just like facebook or for captcha validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a simple form and when user enters all the information and hits the submit botton than a panel should open just a width of 200px and height of 100px inside the same window. which should have two fields one is captcha image and a text box and a check botton and if captcha code is right than panel should automatically close and redirect to another page just like facebook .
all the details of the panel is saved on another php file.

Comment: recaptcha would be better option

Answer (score 2):

Check out [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.com/) , read the documentation and understand how it works (takes only minutes)

How you implement that will be up to you eventually, but basically to do it the way you desire, you'll need to have some knowledge of javascript(jQuery or prototype will make the visual effects easier though).

To be more detailed, the captcha would already have been generated on the form, but the parent container should be hidden with a:

```
$('#captcha-container-id').slideUp();
```

As soon as the form is filled, you could then do a:

```
$('#captcha-container-id').slideDown();
```

The rest is pure PHP

**NOTE: The javascript example is in jQuery**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [recapcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for getting the captions.
You will need to learn javascript to handle the window opening and closing effects

I hope you can handle the rest.